# DNN - Find optimal dropout rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dropout

Is there a way to find the optimal dropout rate for my DNN without retraining it?

maybe some subquestions:

- is it smart to have a dropout after each dense layer?
- would it be enough to have one single dropout layer at the end and just retrain the last layer and not the whole model?

```
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

X_train = X_train_full[5000:]
y_train = y_train_full[5000:]
X_valid = X_train_full[:5000]
y_valid = y_train_full[:5000]

model_dropout = keras.models.Sequential()
model_dropout.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[32, 32, 3]))
for _ in range(20):
    model_dropout.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
    model_dropout.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)) #should be after each layer 

model_dropout.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

# Compile the model
model_dropout.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

# Train the model
result_dropout = model_dropout.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))

# Plot the learning curves
pd.DataFrame(result_dropout.history).plot(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# Evaluate the model
model_dropout.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dropout** is mainly used to regularize the neural network and also one of the techniques to avoid model overfitting. The dropout_rate used in the [Dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout) layer is for zeroing out a few fractions of features from the previous layer to optimize the model. You can use the dropout layer after any layers in the model definition and can test the model efficiency. Also, you can adjust the number of dropout layers and dropout_rate (Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the input units to drop.) accordingly.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#add_dropout) link for more details on adding dropout layers in the model.